# When I apply a material objects loses self shadow

Tags: materials, shaders, shadows

When I apply a material in Blender the objects lose self shadow.

Not the shadow it casts but on its back faces, if that makes sense.

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot of your situation ?

Comment: Yes... We need to at least see the result and your shader. Or even get our hands on your .blend file.